# How to calculate the total salary in Spark Java API

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to SPARK and I am looking into Spark Java API. I have a file

```
1201, John, 2500
1202, Alex, 2800
1203, amith, 3900
1204, javed, 2300
1205, Saminga, 23000
```

Now i need to calculate the total salary and store it in a file. As I am very new for MR /spark Java API , I couldnt able to figure it out. Please can any one help me out from this.

Sample Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.DoubleFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;

import scala.Tuple2;
public class SalarySum {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int k=0;

        if(args.length<1)
        {
            System.out.println("Please provide  input files for processing");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            String inputFile=args[0];
            String outputFile=args[1];
            SparkConf config=new SparkConf().setAppName("Total Salary  Example");
            JavaSparkContext spartContext=new JavaSparkContext(config);

            JavaRDD<String> inputReader=spartContext.textFile(inputFile);

            JavaRDD<String> map=inputReader.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
                @Override
                public Iterable<String> call(String t) throws Exception
                {
                    System.out.println("Flat Map Data: "+t);
                    return Arrays.asList(t);
                }
            });

            JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterable<String>> group=map.groupBy(new Function<String, Integer>() {

                @Override
                public Integer call(String s2) throws Exception
                {
                    String data=s2.split(",")[2].trim();
                    int value=Integer.parseInt(data);
                    System.out.println("Tuple: "+s2 +" : "+data);
                    return value;
                }
            });


            JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> totalSaleData = group.flatMapValues(new Function<Iterable<String>, Iterable<Integer>>() {

                @Override
                public Iterable<Integer> call(Iterable<String> v1)
                        throws Exception 
                {
                    int count=0;
                    for(String str:v1)
                    {
                        String data=str.split(",")[2].trim();
                        int value=Integer.parseInt(data);
                        System.out.println("Iterating Values : "+str);
                        System.out.println("Count: "+count);
                        count =count+value;
                    }
                    return Arrays.asList(count);
                }
            });

            totalSaleData.saveAsTextFile(outputFile);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your input file is txt or csv? Do you want to use RDD and not the Dataframe? What is the expected output to be written in file?

Comment: My input file is text file , I need to use RDD and out must be the sum of complete salary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below using Spark 1.6.

```
public class SparkSalarySum {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkSalarySum").setMaster("local[2]");
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> lines = jsc.textFile("c:\\temp\\test.txt");
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> total = lines.flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(Integer.parseInt(line.split(",")[2].trim())))
            .mapToPair(sal -> new Tuple2<String, Integer>("Total", sal))
            .reduceByKey((x, y) ->  x +  y);
    total.foreach(data -> {
        System.out.println(data._1()+"-"+data._2());
    });
    total.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("c:\\temp\\testOut");
    jsc.stop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Cant we write the same code with JavaSparkContext  API. I am using Spark 1.6 version

Comment: Updated my answer for Spark 1.6.

Comment: But how we store the result in to a text file with this code, I couldn't able to see any methods to store a result in a file

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks abaghel , It worked for me. Can you please provide me any Spark Java links , as i am very new For this API.

Comment: You can read Spark Documentation as it provides samples in Scala, Java, Python and R. You should refer example folder for java from your Spark installation..